# Epsilon-delta proof of $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x^2+9} = 3$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x^2+9} = 3$, given $\epsilon = 0.1$

Here's what I tried:

> $\lvert f(x) - 3 \rvert < \epsilon \implies \sqrt{x^2 + 9} - 3 < 0.1
> > \implies \frac {x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9} + 3} < 0.1$

I'm not able to make any further progress from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$ \delta = 0.1$$

If $$|x-0|<\delta $$

Then

$$      \lvert f(x) - 3 \rvert = \frac {x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 9} + 3} <  \frac {x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 } } =|x|<0.1$$

Answer (score 0):

Now the issue is to choose $\delta$ small enough that if $|x|<\delta$ then you have the desired inequality. Hint: after your simplification, the denominator is now bounded below, so it suffices to work with $Cx^2$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

It will be enough to have $x^2<0.1$ and $\sqrt{x^2+9}+3\geqslant1$. But, in fact, $\sqrt{x^2+9}+3\geqslant3$. So, take $\delta=\sqrt{0.1}$.